# $L^p$-contractivity implies $L^p$-dissipativity?

Tags: operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Does $L^p$-contractivity of an operator semigrop imply the $L^p$-dissipativity of the operator?

Please note the definition of $L^p$-dissipativity:

$(Au, |u|^{p-2}u)\leq 0$  for all $u\in C^1_0(\Omega)$

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Lumer Phillips theorem is the answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumer–Phillips_theorem

Comment: Thank for the feed back. The lumer philips theorem concerns dissipativity, does it still work for the L^p dissipativity ?

Comment: on wikipedia the theorem is stated for a general Banach space. Since $L^p$ is a Banach space this theorem also covers the situation in $L^p$.

Comment: I agree with you but the definition of dissipativity and L^p dissipativity are rather différents

Comment: Okay maybe you can provide the definition in your question because i have never heard about this concept.

Answer (score 1):

*$L^p$-contractivity implies $L^p$-dissipativity?*

I suppose that "$L^p$-contractivity" means
$$\|T(t)\|_{\mathcal L}\leq 1,\quad\forall\ t\geq 0$$
where $T(t):L^p\to L^p$ is the semigroup generated by $A:D(A)\subset L^p\to L^p$.

In this case, according to your definition of $L^p$-dissipativity, the answer is *yes* provided that $ C^1_0(\Omega)\subset D(A)$.

*Proof:*

The $L^p$-contractivity implies that

$$(T(t)u, |u|^{p-2}u)\leq \underbrace{\|T(t)\|}_{\leq 1}\|u\|_{L^p}\underbrace{\||u|^{p-2}u\|_{L^{p/(p-1)}}}_{= \|u\|_{L^p}^{p-1}}\leq\|u\|^p_{L^p},\quad\forall\ u\in L^p.$$
Therefore,
$$(T(t)u-u, |u|^{p-2}u)=(T(t)u, |u|^{p-2}u)-(u, |u|^{p-2}u)\leq \|u\|^p_{L^p}-\|u\|_{L^p}^p=0,\quad\forall\ u\in L^p$$
and thus, multiplying by $\frac{1}{h}$, we obtain
$$\left(\frac{T(t)u-u}{h}, |u|^{p-2}u\right)\leq 0,\quad\forall\ u\in L^p,\; h>0.$$
Taking the limit as $h\to 0^+$, we conclude that
$$(Au, |u|^{p-2}u)\leq 0,\quad\forall\ u\in D(A).\;\square$$

Comment: Thank you @Pedro